# Mahapps e WPF - Como aplicar efeito de "realçar " quando eu passar o Mouse sobre um Tile

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou usando um `Framework` chamado `Mahapps` em meu projeto `WPF` e gostaria de aplicar um efeito de realce no `Tile`, quando eu passasse o mouse sobre ele.

Alguém sabe como fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<Page x:Class="SistemaComercial.Presentation.WPF.Views.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SistemaComercial.Presentation.WPF.Views"
      xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
      xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Foreground="{DynamicResource TextBrush}"
      d:DesignHeight="513"
      Title="MainPage" Width="1138">



    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="LargeTileStyle" TargetType="mah:Tile">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="125" />
            <Setter Property="TitleFontSize" Value="16" />
        </Style>      

        <Style x:Key="SmallTileStyle" TargetType="mah:Tile">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="147" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="125" />
            <Setter Property="TitleFontSize" Value="16" />
        </Style>


    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="0,0,-304,-68" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1442" Height="581" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="87*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="430*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="83*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="259*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="Start"
                   FontWeight="Light"
                   Foreground="Black"
                   FontSize="30"
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,18,233,83" />
            <WrapPanel Height="382" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="940" Margin="0,-72,492,130" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <mah:Tile Title="Mail" Style="{StaticResource LargeTileStyle}" Content="ImageHere" Background="Teal" Margin="3"/>
                <mah:Tile Title="Finance" Style="{StaticResource LargeTileStyle}" Background="Green"/>
                <mah:Tile Title="People" Style="{StaticResource LargeTileStyle}" Background="#D2691E" />
                <mah:Tile Title="Weather" Style="{StaticResource LargeTileStyle}" Background="#1E90FF" />
                <mah:Tile Title="Weather" Style="{StaticResource SmallTileStyle}" Background="#1E90FF" />
                <mah:Tile Title="Store" Style="{StaticResource SmallTileStyle}" Background="Green" />
            </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: pelo que eu li aqui, ele herda um button, então deve haver o evento `MouseHover` nele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tudo o que você precisa é de um `trigger` que corresponde ao evento `IsMouseOver` e alterar a cor do background quando `True`, e usar a cor original quando `False`.

## 1. Criando um Style para o Tile

Criaremos um `style` para o Tile que irá possuir a definição da cor do background do Tile, juntamente com o evento IsMouveOver que irá alterar a cor do mesmo.

Acesse o arquivo *App.xaml* dentro do seu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro da tag `<Application.Resources>` adicione a tag `<ResourceDictionary>` e adicione o seguinte código:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="LargeTileStyle" TargetType="Controls:Tile">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
           </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Note que eu selecionei a cor *Blue* como cor padrão do `background` do `Tile` e a cor *Gray* para a cor do `background` quando o mouse estiver sobre o `Tile`.

Seu arquivo ficará assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## 2. Modificando o Tile

Com o `style` criado, alteramos o `tile` com o `style` criado:

```
<Controls:Tile Title="TileOne" Style="{StaticResource LargeTileStyle}" Margin="10,10,196,169" Width="Auto" />
```

## 3. Declaração da biblioteca MahApps

Note que estou utilizando o nome *Controls* para declarar a biblioteca *MahApps*, tanto no `App.xaml` quanto na classe onde se encontra o `Tile`, no meu caso `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
```

Comment: Obrigado pela precisa ajuda Perozzo!!! :)

Comment: Perozzo,  ele está sublinhando de azul o bloco Value="{StaticResource LargeTileHighlightedBrush}"... O erro informa que o recurso não pode ser resolvido... O que seria?

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta com o que deve fazer.

Comment: Olá Perozzo, não deu certo. Como tenho pouco espaço aqui para inserir o fonte, respondi minha própria pergunta para vc ver como fiz e se precisa alterar algo para funcionar. Obrigado companheiro!

Comment: @JalberRomano Erro feio meu. Irei atualizar minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado Perozzo, funcionou, mas tem um pequeno problema: Cada Tile tem uma cor diferente. Conforme a sua implementação só funciona com uma cor, eu teria que criar um Style para cada cor de Tile no ResouceDictionary. Não tem como setar a cor de cada Tile como fazia antes não?

Comment: Sim, é só criar um style para cada Tile. Não há problema nenhum nisso. Se a resposta te ajudou, por favor marque como resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: Entendi... Obrigado Perozzo!